# DoubleBuffered inaccessible due to it's protection level in Console Application

Tags: c#

I currently have a console based application and I wanted to add a simple invisible form so I could draw some lines on screen, it worked fine however the lines need to move so they flicker a lot as it refreshes.

I thought to add the DoubleBuffered control however it says that it is inaccessible due to the level of protection, usually you would enable that in the design section of a form, is there any way to make it accessible within a console application or would I need to switch to a form application?

```csh
        public static Form f;

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            f = new Form();
            f.DoubleBuffered = true;
            f.Load += OnLoad;

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(f);
        }
```

Shows - Control.DoubleBuffered is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Is `DoubleBuffered` declared as private or protected?

Comment: I think the bigger question is why you added a UI to a console app?  Now if someone wanted to run it from a Windows Service, Task Scheduler, or CI tool they can’t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DoubleBuffered` on `Form` is marked as protected.  That means the value can only be access from the class, or a class derived from it.  The normal way to deal with these sort of values is to only access them from a derived class, like this:

```cs
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }
}

class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form_Load);
    }

    void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: @Novahf note now with Anon’s fine answer your console app is no longer pretending to be a GUI